# Removing space between vertical div

Tags: html, css, image

```
<div class="flex-33">      
      <div class="menu-container">
        <img class="menu-image" src="img/bocadillobody.png" alt="Sandwitch">
        <div class="menu-description">
         <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
         <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon.   </p>
      </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Can some one please help me to eliminate white space between two divs `img` and `.menu-description` please?

I reckon in last 3 hrs I tried all what was explained [here](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=remove%20space%20between%20divs), but only had partial luck, where white-space disappeared, but reappeared on changing browser `width`.

Comment: post a live example (*relevant css etc*)

Comment: Please supply your css code, it's impossible to help you without seeing your styles.

Comment: Change the css of your image to display: block; since inline elements cause that kind of issues

Comment: Thanks all for your comments,   `display: block` as said by dippas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because `img` is an inline level element, set the `img` to `display:block` to became a block level therefore that whitespace is removed.

```css
.flex-33 div {
  border: red solid 1px
}
img {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-33">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <img class="menu-image" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="Sandwitch">
    <div class="menu-description">
      <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
      <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can set `vertical-align:bottom` on `img` because per default `img` has `vertical-align:baseline`

```css
.flex-33 div {
  border: red solid 1px
}
img {
  vertical-align:bottom
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-33">
  <div class="menu-container">
    <img class="menu-image" src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="Sandwitch">
    <div class="menu-description">
      <h4>Sandwitch</h4>
      <p>Powder marshmallow marshmallow brownie carrot cake candy bonbon. Sweet sugar plum gummies caramels tart carrot cake tiramisu cheesecake. Cheesecake biscuit jelly beans. Jelly-o icing chocolate macaroon.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove all padding and margin from the image, as well as the div. Make sure you set the height and width of your image. If you don't, and the image is wider than it is tall, it may be taking up extra space vertically.